# Spring Boot service layer: Unit or Integration tests?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing

I have a service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BookService {

    private final BookRepository bookRepository;

    public Book findOne(Long id) {
        return bookRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }

    public Book getOne(Long id) {
        return bookRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new BadRequestAlertException("entity-not-found", ("Entity with id: " + id + " not found!")));
    }

    public List<Book> getAll() {
        return bookRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Book save(Book book) {
        return bookRepository.save(book);
    }

}
```

I have written Integration tests for both database (BookRepository) and controller layer (BookController which uses BookService). I can't find anywhere examples of integration tests for service layer. If I write unit tests properly, is there any use case for writting integration tests for it? As far as I can tell (it's not a rule, but common use cases):

- Controller - Integration tests
- Service - Unit tests
- Repository - Integration tests

Comment: If we write integration tests, they should - in a best case scenario - trigger the controller and not mock anything else, i.e. the controller calls the (real) service, the service calls the (real) repository, the repository hits the database. Thus, if we integration-test the controller, the service and repository are in the scope of the test as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, so here's how you can think of it ...

1. It makes zero sense to write unit tests for `repositories`, they are only ever covered by integration tests. The choice to use an `in-memory DB` or a proper DB from a Docker container depends on the circumstances, but generally I'd go for a DB in a Docker container, since H2 (even with say `postgres` dialect) is not a complete copy of the `Postgres` DB. Therefore, the tests might run, but the app will crash in production.
2. For `controllers`, you might want to have a mix of unit and integration tests. Test the majority of controller stuff using the `MockMvc` class. And the most critical scenarios are covered by integration tests to test the whole vertical ( 3 layered ) slice of functionality.
3. Now we get to the `services` part. If your service has complicated business logic, which you want to validate, then it **must** be covered by unit tests, so that you can do *a lot* of checks is a small amount of time.
   Also, it makes sense to cover some of the most basic scenarios by integration tests. In **specifically your case**, the business logic inside the service layer is extremely simple, so I'd go for just the integration tests. If and when it gets more complicated, you can add also some unit tests, where you **mock out** the repository classes to have blazing fast test times and being able to make a lot of check without slowing down the `CI` pipeline for everyone on the project.

In general, try to always follow the [test pyramid](https://martinfowler.com/articles/practical-test-pyramid.html) pattern and use the best possible [testing libraries](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing) provided by the Spring Boot ecosystem.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I am still not sure about the service layer though. If Integration tests written for controllers should cover all 3 layers, is there any point for writing them for the service layer? Well written unit tests should cover all the business logic inside the layer and along with controller/repository integration tests everything (layer-wise) should be covered? In my case, if I've written controller and repository IT, what would the service IT look like?

Comment: OK, so a service layer can be used by more than two presentation layers. Say you have 2 sets of controllers, which use the same services under the hood. One returns HTML and the other is a REST API.

You don't want to duplicate all the tests for each of the controllers. You just want to cover the basics and move all the shared stuff into the service layer tests.

Until you have more than 1 views there is no difference what you do integration tests on service or controller, but once you have 1+ views, then all the common tests need to go into the service tests.

Comment: Ultimately, there is no right or wrong answer here ... unlike math ... it all depends on the project as there can be many nuances.

Comment: If this answer has helped you create clarity in the mind on the topic, please mark it as accepted so others can reuse it too :)